# Enable vertical scrolling in Javascript Modern UI app

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

I am trying to create a Javascript Modern UI app. The problem is, vertical scrolling doesn't work. As I try to scroll using the mouse scroll, the page (HTML file) just stays there and does nothing, and it only displays the contents that are at the top of the page (the contents that fit on the screen at the beginning)

How can I enable vertical scrolling?

Comment: have you VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" and
VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"

Comment: is that C#? I'm using javascript

Comment: did you set the CSS property "overflow" to auto?

Comment: yes I did, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's because of the `height:auto` property. Remove it and voila ~

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is several years old, but for me this was fixed by overriding the `overflow` property on the `html` element

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
```